# Фоновая работа программы Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, я бы хотел узнать, есть ли в python какой-то модуль или скрипт, с помощью которого можно проводить операции вне программы(то есть, например: когда я сверну консоль программы и зайду в ворд, и при нажатии на какую-то клавишу что-либо происходило)?

Например:
Нажимаю на на букву - Б, у меня идёт замены буквы:

```
.replace('Б', 'B')
.replace('Г', 'G')
```

Comment: казалось бы: при чём тут язык программирования python?

Comment: Python - не подходящий для этого язык, но [модуль](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) всё же есть.

Comment: моете подсказать название модуля?